# Node.js - How does a readable stream react to a file that is still being written?

Tags: node.js, stream

I have found a lot of information on how to pump, or pipe data from a read stream to a write stream in Node.  The newest version even auto pauses, and resumes for you.  However, I have a different need and would like some help.

I am writing a video file using ffmpeg (to a local file, not a writeable stream), and I would like to create a readstream that reads the data as it gets written. Obviously, the read stream speed will surpass how quickly ffmpeg encodes the file. What will happen when the read stream reaches the end of data before ffmpeg finishes writing the file? I assume it will stop the read stream before the file is fully encoded.

Anyone have any suggestions for the best way to pause/resume the read stream so that it doesn't reach the end of the locally encoding file until the encoding is 100% complete?

In summary:

This is what people normally do: readStream --> writeStream (using .pipe)

This is what I want to do: local file (in slow creation process) --> readStream

As always, thanks to the stackOverflow community.

Comment: Note: If it makes it easier, I am able to use ffmpeg to encode to a stream. Is there a way to do a reverse .pipe? Like, writeStream --> readStream? Unfortunately, writeStreams dont have a 'data' listener.

Comment: Check out the [`options` for `Stream.pipe`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/streams.html#stream.pipe). It allows you to pass a flag (`{ end: false }`) to keep the destination stream open. This may be the first thing you should look into.

Comment: Thanks Dominic. However, this option keeps the destination writeStream open, where in my situation, I'd need 'end: false' for the readStream.  Unfortunately for me, I need something like a reverse stream.pipe... if that makes any sense.

Comment: Could you have perhaps have read the output before writing it to the file? `ffmpegEncodeWriteStream.pipe(throughStream).pipe(file)`. This way you get all the same data as streaming from the file at the end, but you don't need to think about when the file creation is actually finished.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [growing-file](https://github.com/felixge/node-growing-file) module is what you want.

Comment: DeaDEnD strikes again! The module is exactly what I was looking for. I will try to implement it as soon as I can, and will post back later. Thanks!