# How can I play an audio file while converting it with ffmpeg in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg

I created a simple video-to-audio converter with ffmpeg for my discord.js bot:

```
let stream = //an mp4 stream
ffmpeg(stream)
  .toFormat("mp3")
  .stream(fs.createWriteStream("./audio.mp3"))
  .on("end", () => {
    connection.playStream(fs.createReadStream("./audio.mp3"))
  });
```

This all works fine, but using .on() to play the file - only after it completely finishes converting - can take a while.

Is there an efficient way to use connection.playStream to **play the audio file or stream as the ffmpeg conversion is still happening?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up seeing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566736/node-js-how-does-a-readable-stream-react-to-a-file-that-is-still-being-written) and used the [growing-file module](https://github.com/felixge/node-growing-file) to stream the file as it was being converted. Here's the general idea:

```
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("./audio.mp3");
const stream = //mp4 stream
ffmpeg(stream)
  .toFormat("mp3")
  .pipe(writeStream);
const file = GrowingFile.open("./audio.mp3");
connection.playStream(file);
```

The only downside to this is that I am still forced to download the stream to an mp3 file, while I would prefer to skip that step and simply use `connection.playStream` to play ffmpeg's `pipe`.

If anyone has an idea of how to **skip the mp3 download and simply stream/pipe to connection.playStream**, it would be appreciated!